# about open function in c

Tags: c, file-descriptor

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    int in_fd = open("here_doc.tmp", O_CREAT | O_RDWR | O_TRUNC, 0644);
    int out_fd = open("outfile", O_CREAT | O_RDWR | O_APPEND, 0644);
    
    write(in_fd, "hello 1\n", 8);
    write(in_fd, "Pello 1\n", 8);
    write(in_fd, "Yello 1\n", 8);


/* ********* I wonder why the two line below are necessary ******* */
    close(in_fd);
    in_fd = open("here_doc.tmp", O_RDWR, 0644);
  
    dup2(in_fd, 0);
    dup2(out_fd, 1);
    close (in_fd);
    close (out_fd);
    
    char *argv[]= {"cat", NULL};
    execve("/bin/cat", argv, NULL);
}
```

I want to make code to work like "<<(heredoc)" so I practice how to use "open function"

I think `open("here_doc.tmp, some_option)` need only once.

It can create here_doc.tmp and write well but can't transmit to `execve`

and then I know to make it work properly i need append that two line but I don't know why
I wonder why those is necessary

(clang-1200.0.32.28)

Comment: Because the head is at the end of the file. You may not need to close/ropen just lseek to rewind to the head.

Comment: You need to add "here_doc.tmp" to the argv-list for the cat-command.

Answer (score 0):

After a successful `write(2)` operation, the file offset indicator is moved forward by the number of bytes written.

Here, the file is closed in order for the offset indicator to be reset. You may call `lseek(2)` instead of `close(2)` to reposition it.